# When does a variable need to be declared outside a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This code only works when the "counter" variable is declared outside the function:

```
let counter = 0;
function counterFunction () {
document.getElementById('counterValue').innerHTML = counter++;
}
```

It's a simple counter that increments by one when a button is clicked.

Comment: @basic that is not a duplicate here - OP is not asking about scope.

Comment: Pretty much never, but it's the easiest way to maintain a state of a value between the function calls.

Comment: Louie - When you create & initialize the `counter` variable inside the function, each time you call the function, the `counter` gets set to zero. So it appears to never update. Putting it outside allows it to update without being reset.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable using let you're declaring that variable inside the current block, a block could be an if or a loop.

Example:

```js
if (condition===true){
  let counter = 0;
  counter++ //The variable is defined here
}

counter++ //The variable is undefined here
```

The limits of a block are the curly braces "{" "}"

You must declare a variable outside a function only if you plan to use it outside, otherwise that variable must be declare inside.

Comment: ... and if that "block" is a function which returns, when it does so the value disappears. What the code wants here is a value that is retained.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments made to the original question ... references to some very important things there *e.g.* the difference between `var` and `let`.

Obviously, if the variable were declared *inside* the function, it would be "local to it," and its value would be discarded each time the function returned.